# Angular - bootstrap modal inside ng-repeat - how to update data on the main scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ng repeat to display a table, the table contains an 'edit' button that opens a modal. Once the data is updated in the modal I dont know how to get the modal scope data back to the main scope data used to generate the table.

Basically I want to be able to use the data from the modal to update the main ng-repeat table.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8gn8hjd/2/)

here is the function executed when closing the modal:

```
$scope.customer = customer;

   $scope.ok = function (customer) {

      $modalInstance.close($scope.customer);
                    };

});
```

In my example, you can see that the "customer.details" are not updated when updated in the modal.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `ng-model` instead of `ng-modal` it works.

i edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h3erp1w/3/)

Comment: Hi Joey, Thanks for your fast reply but I the fiddle you have linked to doesnt seem to have your change (or at least I cant find it). Just to make sure Im extra clear on what Im trying to do, the text inputted into the modal should update the text next to the respective edit button when the modal is closed.

Comment: Awesome - shoot, cant believe I wasted so much time on such a simple mistake! Thank you!